# Handling HeroCards responses In Microsoft Bot Framework v4 for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook, async-await, botframework

I am using NodeJs API of `Microsoft Bot Framework v4`. And my dialogs are not hardcoded in the `ActivityHandler`, I just call from there. I am using Waterfall dialogs. So when I try to show `Carousel card` on messenger (which is `HeroCard` on Microsoft bot framework), it shows up successfully but when I click any button on cards, there is no response for next dialog.

I tried to handle on `onMessage` hook but, it just tries to validate the response and throw errors.

....

```
 ListItems extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(userProfileState, conversionStateAccessor) {
        super(LIST_ITEMS);
        this.userState = userProfileState;
        this.conversionState = conversionStateAccessor;
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(LIST_ITEMS_DIALOG, [
            this.sendItems.bind(this),
            this.handleItems.bind(this)
        ]
        ));
        this.initialDialogId = LIST_ITEMS_DIALOG;
    }


    async sendItems(step) {
        .......
        await step.context.sendActivity({ attachments: cards }); // this line is working
    }

    async handleItems(step) {
     console.log(step.result) // the response is not in 'step.result.value' if i click a button on cards

}
```

Thanks for your help

---- **I added more detail** -----

I am using this template to create cards

```
const card = CardFactory.heroCard('title', 'subtitle', ['imagelink'], [
    { type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
        title: 'product 1',
        value: 'product_1'
    },
    { type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
        title: 'product 1',
        value: 'product_1' 
    },
]);
  await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [card] });
```

Cars can be created successfully but the problem is, after that, I send a prompt to let the user turn the main menu if the user wants.

so I send them like that

```
 await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [card] }); 
 await step.prompt(LIST_ITEMS_MENU_PROMPT, menuPromptPayload);
```

And if the user clicks a button on cards, an error is thrown because I think the framework waits for prompt's answers. Couldn't catch the card's button's payload/

Comment: Can you provide your code for the cards, as well? And, what is the interaction from the user in this? What result are you looking to find in value?

Comment: Hey Steven! I updated the answer and the added more information! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct your bot to wait for and return a response following the `sendActivity` in `sendItems`. Similarly, you will encounter an error in the `handleItems` if you don't tell the bot to continue on since there is nothing happening other than console logging.

```js
async sendItems(step) {
.......
    await step.context.sendActivity({ attachments: cards });

    // Tells the bot to wait. Normally, on `sendActivity`, it continues on to the next step.
    // "DialogTurnStatus" can be found in the `botbuilder-dialogs` package.
    return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting }; 
}

async handleItems(step) {
    console.log(step.result);
    return step.next();  // Tells the bot to continue to the next step.
}
```

Hope of help!

Comment: It works if I don't prompt user after sending herocards, but I need to send a prompt for let user go back the main menu via Quick Reply buttons. Thanks For Help!